# Use 'as' multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have this:

```
SELECT
   posts.id,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesCount,
   (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesUp
FROM posts WHERE posts.id = 1
```

How do i get the difference between **votesCount** and **votesUp** without doing other SELECT? Something like:

```
SELECT
   posts.id,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesCount,
   (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesUp,
   votesCount - votesUp AS votesDown
FROM posts WHERE posts.id = 1
```

Is it possible, or do i have to call another SELECT anyway?
Thanks.

Btw, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your English is fine. Your MySQL is troubling ;-). Actually, it IS possible, but it's just as easy (and more efficient) to use the method Notulysses describes below.

Comment: The way you are doing these queries is VERY inefficient.. basically for every row in posts, you are selecting every row in votes to compare two times.. example.. 100 rows in post and just 1 vote per post(100 votes), you are comparing 100 * 100 * 100.. thats a million checks with just 100 rows in the database. left join the table and do your aggregates outside. that should increase performance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you join in the votes instead of using subqueries, then you can easily reuse the aggregates:

```
select
  p.id,
  count(v.post) as votesCount,
  sum(v.vote) as votesUp,
  count(v.post) - sum(v.vote) as votesDown
from
  posts p
  left join votes v on v.post = p.id
where
  p.id = 1
group by
  p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sub queries don't quite make sense. Typically you want to use subqueries as a last resort in preference of joins. For example:

```
SELECT
    posts.id, COUNT(votes.*) AS votesCount, SUM(vote) AS votesUp 
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post = posts.id
WHERE
    posts.id = 1
GROUP BY posts.id
```

This also makes it easier to do the subtraction, though it does unfortunately require a bit of repetition (aliases cannot be used in subsequent columns :/):

```
SELECT
    posts.id, COUNT(votes.*) AS votesCount, SUM(vote) AS votesUp,
    COUNT(votes.id) - SUM(vote) AS votesDown
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post = posts.id
WHERE
    posts.id = 1
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Comment: I don't think that rogue * in your count is going to sit nicely with MySQL

Comment: @scrowler Ah, good catch. Wasn't thinking about the JOIN and the `*` :D

Comment: @scrowler count(*) is one of the fastest ways to count in mysql (performance wise). do a test to clarify.. read this blog also http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/   ------- count * is probably more the preferred way

Comment: @JohnRuddell There was actually a semantic error with it: `COUNT(*)` is ambiguous as to which table the `*` means.

Comment: Ahh i gotcha.. thought he was saying you should count off of the column... my bad. votes.* is what it should be :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Not sure if that article applies since it is (or should be) a non-null column. Can never trust the MySQL optimizer to do what you think it will do though, so might be worth changing, I suppose :p.

Answer (score -3):

Not even another nested SELECT?

```
    SELECT
    posts.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesCount,
    (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesUp
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN vote=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM votes WHERE votes.post = posts.id) AS votesDown
    FROM posts WHERE posts.id = 1
```

Comment: Having seen Corbin and Guffa's answers I just slapped myself on the forehead and thought "of course! why didn't I think of that!"